# PHP Warning: Module 'pcntl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php

I am running a PHP file every day (Crontab - everything runs on the server [cli]) located on my server to collect data from an API. I am using forking in my process and for some reason I started getting these errors displayed on `/var/mail/root`.

```
From root@myserver  Thu Nov 17 11:09:01 2016
Return-Path: <root@myserver>
X-Original-To: root
Delivered-To: root@myserver
Received: by myserver (Postfix, from userid 0)
        id D8D111040C1; Thu, 17 Nov 2016 11:09:01 +0200 (IST)
From: root@myserver (Cron Daemon)
To: root@myserver
Subject: Cron <root@myserver>   [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php                                                                                                                               /sessionclean
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
Message-Id: <20161117090901.D8D111040C1@myserver>
Date: Thu, 17 Nov 2016 11:09:01 +0200 (IST)

PHP Warning:  Module 'pcntl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

I googled the error and came across this page: 
http://www.somacon.com/p520.php

which says I might be loading prefork more than once, running `php -v` doesn't output any error. But it doesn't make sence because it's from cli and not apache2.

these are my php.ini used by cli:

```
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini


root@server:/home/server# php -v
PHP 7.0.13-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.13-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
You have new mail in /var/mail/root
```

Extensions that are compiled-in to my PHP binary:

```
root@server:/home/server# php -m
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

I'm almost sure that the problem isn't "prefork running more than once" - What can it be?

Comment: Is this pncl module also in your php.ini file? If so, maybe remove it from there since it's already compiled into the php executable.

Comment: You mean editing `/etc/php/php7.0/cli/php.ini` ? 

I tried searching the file for "pncl" and cant find anything regarding it.@this.lau_

Comment: how about in `/etc/php/php7.0/mods-available`?